# Prove independence of variance estimator and mean estimator in normal distribution

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, independence

How to prove that $S^2$ and $\bar{X}$ are independent given that $X_i \sim$ normal$(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to prove this , I will discuss two possibel ways
1)
s^2 is a function of (x-xbar), so it is enough to show that cov(xbar,x-xbar)=0
tehn you can use the theorem that for normal distrubution zero covariance means independence.

Assuem n is number of observations from x

cov(xbar,x-xbar)=cov(xbar,x)-cov(xbar,xbar)=cov(1/n*sum(x),x)-var(xbar)=
1/n*cov(x,x)-var(xbar)=1/n*var(x)-var(xbar)=1/n*sigma^2-sigma^2/n=0

2) The second way is from Basus theorem which states that a complete sufficient statistic is independent of any ancillary statistic. 
Thus you can show that xbar is complete and suffieint for mu and s^2 is ancillary for mu, thus xbar and s^2 are independent by basus theorem.